# How to build a web app with GraphQL + parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform, reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I would like to use parse and graphQL for a new app. It will essentially work with non logged in users, where people share a link and collaborate on some add hoc item. This will plan a meeting at a certain location.

IS anyone aware of a solution or know of a way to approach this? It seems like it would be an awesome way to make apps.

EDIT

PARSE IS DEAD

Comment: hmm strange close votes.

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, you could certainly build a GraphQL server that was backed by Parse objects!

On the server, you'd build out your GraphQL types as usual; for example, if you had a Todo object and a User object in your Parse Schema (and were using `graphql` and `graphql-relay` from npm), you might end up with objects like

```js
// Build the GraphQL Todo type.
var GraphQLTodo = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Todo',
  fields: () => ({
    content: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (obj) => obj.get('content')
    },
    done: {
      type: GraphQLBoolean,
      resolve: (obj) => obj.get('done')
    },
    user: {
      type: GraphQLUser,
      resolve: (obj) => obj.get('user')
    }
  }),
});

// Build the connection from User to Todo
var {connectionType, edgeType} = connectionDefinitions({
  name: 'UserTodo',
  nodeType: GraphQLTodo,
});

// Build the GraphQL User type.
var GraphQLUser = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => ({
    todosConnection: {
      type: connectionType,
      args: connectionArgs,
      resolve: (obj, args) => new Parse.Query(Todo).equalTo('user', obj).find()
    }
  },
});
```

If the user has signed in on the client, you could potentially pass up a session token to the server to allow for the parse queries to be made with that session token (for ACL reasons).

Comment: I just realised who you are, and its an honour to have your feedback Daniel :)

Comment: I wonder if the logic could be embedded inside of Parse.com cloud code instead of having a node server. Maybe we could ask the guys at parse if they plan to do anything specific with GraphQL too.

Comment: It would be fantastic if Parse could add GraphQL support out of the box.  Given that parse is owned by Facebook, I suspect it's just a matter of time.

Comment: A bit late, but this is an active discussion on parse-server and we'll be working on it!