# How to use a parse session token to make requests with graphql

Tags: session, authentication, parse-server, graphql, relay

I have a parse app and I want to send in the sessionToken with each request so I know which user is accessing what. Just like this post mentioned.

[How to build a web app with GraphQL + parse.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570272/how-to-build-a-web-app-with-graphql-parse-com/32616055#32616055)

Daniel left this comment and I can't seem to do what he mentions.

> If the user has signed in on the client, you could potentially pass up a session token to the server to allow for the parse queries to be made with that session token (for ACL reasons).

In Relay, I see that you can inject the sessionToken into the networkLayer via the `headers`,
But in my graphql server, I can't seem to access this sessionToken and passion into graphql via the `rootValue` property.

Has anyone figured out how to use parse-server and authentication?
The F8 app has it stubbed out currently has it marked as a `TODO` and I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

[Express-Graphql supports a `context` option](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql#options) which will be passed as the last argument to all of your resolver functions. You could pass a Parse session token as a header to any `/graphql` requests, and then forward that through `context` like so:

```
import graphqlHTTP from 'express-graphql';

const app = express();

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP((req) => ({
  // ...
  context: {
    parseSessionToken: req.headers['parse-session-token'],
  },
})));
```

Now inside a resolver function you can use this token with your queries to ensure appropriate ACL is enforced:

```
function resolve (_, args, context) {
  return new Parse.Query('MyClass')
    .first({ sessionToken: context.parseSessionToken });
}
```

If you're using Relay on the client side, use [`Relay.injectNetworkLayer`](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-network-layer.html) to include this header like so:

```
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('http://example.com/graphql', {
    headers: {
      'parse-session-token': Parse.User.current().getSessionToken(),
    },
  })
);
```

If you're using Apollo Client, use [`createNetworkInterface`](http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-client/index.html#createNetworkInterface) in a middleware function to supply headers:

```
import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client';

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface('http://example.com/graphql');

networkInterface.use([{
  applyMiddleware(req, next) {
    if (!req.options.headers) {
      req.options.headers = {};  // Create the header object if needed.
    }
    req.options.headers['parse-session-token'] = Parse.User.current().getSessionToken();
    next();
  }
}]);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface,
});
```

Comment: Thanks @namuol, I'm using Relay and I want to add a login functionality on the client side to grab the user's token. Is there any simple way of doing this? Do I need to create a separate API on express side or I can use graphQL to do this?